# Expand features in shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geotiff-tiff, topography

I have a shapefile with 634k features that when I open in QGIS is filtered to 6 squares. How can I expand it to get all the points, I need to make a topo map from it.

[image: QGIS Attribute Table Screenshot]

Comment: I could be because an object filter is activated. Test your layer (right-click: properties, go to source-tab an check there if there is an expression activeted under object-filter. In this case you should delete it to see all features.